# mysql doesn't fetch existing records when using where clause

Tags: mysql

I have a column with id of 780 and file_name of `소유22.jpg`

but when I use where query of `select * FROM attachments WHERE attachments.file_name LIKE '%소유%';` Mysql doesn't fetch my record whose is id is 780 which fits the query.

What's wrong about this?

```
mysql> select * FROM attachments WHERE id = 780;
+-----+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
| id  | image              | created_at          | updated_at          | image_width | image_height | file_name          |
+-----+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
| 780 | 소유22.jpg       | 2014-10-21 00:58:20 | 2014-10-21 00:58:20 |         518 |          805 | 소유22.jpg       |
+-----+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * FROM attachments WHERE attachments.file_name LIKE '%소유%';
+-----+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------------------------+
| id  | image                                | created_at          | updated_at          | image_width | image_height | file_name                            |
+-----+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------------------------+
| 144 | 소유_어반자카파_녹음실.jpg           | 2014-09-19 03:15:08 | 2014-10-13 07:02:21 |        5190 |         3438 | 소유_어반자카파_녹음실.jpg           |
| 404 | 소유_어반자카파__틈.jpg              | 2014-09-29 08:09:27 | 2014-10-13 07:02:23 |        1400 |          934 | 소유_어반자카파__틈.jpg              |
+-----+--------------------------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+--------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: what is your collation on tables and connection?

Comment: [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-cjk.html#qandaitem-A-11-1-12](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-cjk.html#qandaitem-A-11-1-12) this could be of some help to you

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry. I've changed my screeenshot to copy-and-paste.

Comment: There's some combining going on with the characters above. For everyone else: There are four characters within the string used with `LIKE`, and there are percent signs on **both sides** of the Korean characters, even though it looks like they're only on one side above: http://farsightsoftware.com/utils/unicode-show-me.html?%25%EC%86%8C%EC%9C%A0%25

Comment: @JevgenijsVaikulis collation is utf8_general_ci and connection is local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The record you have in 780, 소유 was encoded as ᄉ ᅩ ᄋ ᅲ (4 characters)

But your search term is 소유 (2 characters)

http://farsightsoftware.com/utils/unicode-show-me.html?%EC%86%8C%EC%9C%A0
vs
http://farsightsoftware.com/utils/unicode-show-me.html?%E1%84%89%E1%85%A9%E1%84%8B%E1%85%B2

Comment: Oh.. I see the problem.. then which make 소유 to 'ㅅㅗㅇㅠ'? is it picture's encoding problem? or uploader's encoding problem? or db's encoding problem? I'm using mysql for rails.

Comment: and when I attempt to this query select * FROM attachments WHERE attachments.file_name LIKE '%ㅅㅗㅇㅠ%'; It returns an empty set.

Comment: try copy and paste this, it should show record 780.  like "%소유%"

Comment: Then, if you copy and paste this, it should show 144 and 404.  like "%소유%"

Comment: Oh... interesting...this 소유 and that 소유 is different..!

Comment: Yes, that's all I can find out.  I don't understand how Korean characters are inputted and stored, so I can't explain why that is happening.  But at least now you have some idea why your query didn't work.